# Using template to handle string and wstring

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have following two functions:

```
void bar(const std::string &s)
{
    someCFunctionU(s.c_str());
}

void bar(const std::wstring &s)
{
    someCFunctionW(s.c_str());
}
```

Both of these call some C function which accepts `const char *` or `const wchar_t *` and have `U` or `W` suffixes respectively. I would like to create a template function to handle both of these cases. I tried following attempt:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const std::basic_string<T> &s)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
        someCFunctionU(s.c_str());
    else
        someCFunctionW(s.c_str());
}
```

But this does not seem to work correctly. If I call:

```
foo("abc");
```

this will not compile. Why is that? why a compiler is not able to deduce the proper type `T` to `char`? Is it possible to create one function which would handle both std::string and std::wstring?

Comment: `"abc"` is `const char*` and not a std::(w)string

Comment: It's actually a `const char[N]`, but it will decay to a `const char*`

Comment: @NathanOliver Why would it decay? During deduction, the parameter is a reference. And during constructor call, it will use the the overload which takes `std::initializer_list<char>`.

Comment: @felix I didn't mean during deduction.  I just mean generally it will decay to a `char*`.   I should have been more specific.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, sometimes. But not in this context. I don't know which part you mean. Problem is that such decay won't happen here in any part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> this will not compile. Why is that? why a compiler is not able to deduce the proper type T to char?

As better explained by others, `"abc"` is a `char[4]`, so is convertible to a `std::basic_string<char>` but isn't a `std::basic_string<char>`, so can't be deduced the `T` type as `char` for a template function that accept a `std::basic_string<T>`.

> Is it possible to create one function which would handle both std::string and std::wstring?

Yes, it's possible; but what's wrong with your two-function-in-overloading solution?

Anyway, if you really want a single function and if you accept to write a lot of casuistry, I suppose you can write something as follows

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const & s)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, std::string> )
        someCFunctionU(s.c_str());                       
    else if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<T, char const *>)
        someCFunctionU(s);
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, std::wstring> )
        someCFunctionW(s.c_str());
    else if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<T, wchar_t const *> )
        someCFunctionW(s);
    // else exception ?
}
```

or, a little more synthetic but less efficient

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T const & s)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string> )
        someCFunctionU(std::string{s}.c_str());
    else if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::wstring> )
        someCFunctionW(std::wstring{s}.c_str());
    // else exception ?
}
```

So you should be able to call `foo()` with `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `char *`, `wchar_t *`, `char[]` or `wchar_t[]`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that in `foo("abc");`, `"abc"` is not a `std::string` or a `std::wstring`, it is a `const char[N]`.  Since it isn't a `std::string` or a `std::wstring` the compiler cannot deduce what `T` should be and it fails to compile.  The easiest solution is to use what you already have.  The overloads will be considered and it is a better match to convert `"abc"` to a `std::string` so it will call that version of the function.

If you want you could use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)/`std::wstring_view` instead of `std::string`/`std::wstring` so you don't actually allocate any memory if you pass the function a string literal.  That would change the overloads to

```
void bar(std::string_view s)
{
    someCFunctionU(s.data());
}

void bar(std::wstring_view s)
{
    someCFunctionW(s.data());
}
```

Do note that `std::basic_string_view` can be constructed without having a null terminator so it is possible to pass a `std::basic_string_view` that won't fulfill the null terminated c-string requirement that your C function has.  In that case the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmm. `string_view` can't guarantee a null-terminated string, so passing `s.data()` to the C-style function is dangerous and should probably be avoided, since that C-style function expects a null-terminated string. If the C-style function could be changed to take a pointer and a length, all would be fine. Alternatively, there may be some non-standard `string_view` implementations which guarantee null-termination, meaning that they can only be at the end of a string

Comment: @Justin That really upsets me with `string_view` that we can't do this.  They give me this nice shinny thing but then rip the carpet out from under my feet.  I'll put a warning in the answer for the OP, just so they know, but it should be okay if the only feed strings/c-strings to the function.

Comment: `string_view` with guaranteed null-termination is not as useful. It means that the `string_view` can only point to the end of strings, rather than any substring.

Comment: @Justin That's why I really wanted a `slice` class.  I always envisioned a `string_view` as a read only view of a string with all the member functions. A `slice` or `string_slice` would have the non-guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exist a type, i.e. `std::basic_string<char>`, which can be copy initialized from expression `"abc"`. So you can call a function like `void foo(std::basic_string<char>)` with argument `"abc"`.

And no, you can't call a function template `template <class T> void foo(const std::basic_string<T> &s)` with argument `"abc"`. Because in order to figure out whether the parameter can be initialized by the argument, the compiler need to determine the template parameter `T` first. It will try to match `const std::basic_string<T> &` against `const char [4]`. And it will fail.

The reason why it will fail is because of the template argument deduction rule. The actual rule is very complicated. But in this case, for `std::basic_string<char>` to be examined during the deduction, compiler will need to look for a proper "converting constructor", i.e. the constructor which can be called implicitly with argument `"abc"`, and such lookup isn't allowed by the standard during deduction.

Yes, it is possible to handle std::string and std::wstring in one function template:

```
void foo_impl(const std::string &) {}
void foo_impl(const std::wstring &) {}

template <class T>
auto foo(T &&t) {
    return foo_impl(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

Comment: `std::basic_string<char>` is exactly the same as `std::string`

Comment: @Justin Yes, std::string is its alias. But the original question is using std::basic_string.  And in this context, using std::string is inconvenient.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround in C++17 is:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T &s)
{
    std::basic_string_view sv{s}; // Class template argument deduction

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<typename decltype(sv)::value_type, char>)
        someCFunctionU(sv.data());
    else
        someCFunctionW(sv.data());
}
```

And to avoid issue mentioned by Justin about non-null-terminated string

```
template <typename T> struct is_basic_string_view : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> struct is_basic_string_view<basic_string_view<T>> : std::true_type
{};

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_basic_string_view<T>::value> foo(const T &s)
{
    std::basic_string_view sv{s}; // Class template argument deduction

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<typename decltype(sv)::value_type, char>)
        someCFunctionU(sv.data());
    else
        someCFunctionW(sv.data());
}
```

Comment: This has the same danger I mentioned in NathanOliver's answer: if you pass a non-null-terminated `string_view` to `foo(...)`, this will accept it, passing a non-null-terminated string to the C functions, which is likely to cause problems.

Comment: @Justin: Safer version added.